# How to use my 6GB of free ram to optimize ubuntu12.04?

Tags: 12.04, kernel, ram, optimization

I also want to load faster on boot. If possible, can I shift all temp file hard disk operation to RAM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that Ubuntu already does a great job with RAM management. I only have 1024 RAM memory, not very fast RAM too, but my swap space is rarely used for system operations, and I do not have issues with a faster boot or usual system operations. The problems I have are generated by my CPU, which is kind of ancient, but even so it gets the job done with honor :) .

If you really want to optimize Ubuntu for speed and RAM management you could install first a few extra packages with Synaptic Package Manager or in the terminal emulator:

1. Preload is one of them, faster boot, better service management:

   ```
         sudo apt-get install preload
   ```
2. Bum is another package that you can use to get rid of all the services that you do not need at startup, services and daemons that you do not use at all. Use BUM with extreme care, it can have a negative impact on your system if you disable wrong services. Test BUM first by disabling services one by one, I mean all those system services that you don't use at all! Install BUM with this code:

   ```
         sudo apt-get install bum
   ```
3. You can also disable graphical boot which adds a few extra seconds to total boot time. To do that you need to edit the grub file located in /etc/default/grub:

   ```
         gksu leafpad /etc/default/grub
   ```

Go to the line saying:

```
         # Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
         #GRUB_TERMINAL=console
```

Once there, remove the '#' to uncomment line GRUB_TERMINAL=console and get a faster boot in  a non-graphical console. The result should look like this:

```
         # Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
         GRUB_TERMINAL=console
```

Save the file located in /etc/default/grub and close it. Very important, update grub immediately after that using this code:

```
         sudo update-grub
```

Finally, change your swappiness value from 60 to 10 as follows:

Edit sysctl.conf file by typing in the terminal this code:

```
 gksu leafpad /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Once the file is opened, go right to the end of the file and add your swappiness and cache parameters. If there are similar lines in there and vm.swappiness is already 10, you don't need to do anything, otherwise you have to add the following lines right at the end of the file:

```
# Decrease swap usage to a workable level
vm.swappiness=10
# Improve cache management
vm.vfs_cache_pressure=50
```

Comment: if my RAM is never fully used up,so what is the point to decrease swappiness?

Comment: It says - 'Decrease swap usage to a workable level', and it forces services to stay in RAM, and make swap pretty much useless. Anyway, this is the right tweak for machines having more than 1 GB RAM installed.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention, my RAM memory is also never fully used up, and I only have 1024 RAM memory installed. I usually boot into XFCE session like they use in Xubuntu, and never need more than 300 MB RAM for this.

Answer (score 0):

do you mean that not all your RAM is recognized? the only reason I can think of that could happen is that you might be using the 32 bit version of Ubuntu, if so use the 64 bit.

If you want a faster boot time you are talking about read speeds of the hard drives. I would advise a SSD that will make a big difference in boot time. but I cannot imagine that you can do something with your ram to speed up boot since everything stored on ram is lost when you power off.

maybe there is a way to store temp files in ram, I have never heard about it. but I wonder whether the read speed of the temp files is limiting your system.

Comment: thanx to adding some linux information in my brain btw I'm using 64 bit precise!